# GTK C "Could not find signal handler ''. Did you compile with -rdynamic? "

Tags: c, gtk, glade

So my little attempt of trying to close a window  a second (not destroy the main window) went a little bit ahead, but hit another rock. the code compiles with no errors or warnings, but when i push the button triggering "on_window_sidebar1_back_clicked" the console running said program spews out the error `"Could not find signal handler 'on_window_sidebar1_back_clicked'. Did you compile with -rdynamic?`.

ive run my compiler with -rdynamic and it doesnt help.

Part of code responsible for closing the window:

```
void on_window_sidebar1_back_clicked() 
 {
    void
    gtk_close_window(secondWindow); //sedondWindow is defined further up. no errors related to it.
 }
```

my window_main.glade (Warning! LONG)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_main">
    <property name="width_request">800</property>
    <property name="height_request">480</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">test</property>
    <property name="default_width">800</property>
    <property name="default_height">480</property>
    <property name="skip_taskbar_hint">True</property>
    <property name="decorated">False</property>
    <property name="deletable">False</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_main_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed" id="fixed1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="lbl_test">
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">30</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">test</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">400</property>
            <property name="y">190</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="lbl_count">
            <property name="name">3</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">30</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">400</property>
            <property name="y">240</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="btn_count">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">get count</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">34</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_btn_count_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">400</property>
            <property name="y">290</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="nonconfigured2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">100</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">700</property>
            <property name="y">200</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="sidebar_1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">  open 
window
    1</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">100</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_sidebar_1_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">700</property>
            <property name="y">100</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_sidebar1">
    <property name="width_request">800</property>
    <property name="height_request">480</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <property name="hide_titlebar_when_maximized">True</property>
    <property name="decorated">False</property>
    <property name="deletable">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed" id="fixed2">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="window_sidebar1_back">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">BACK</property>
            <property name="width_request">70</property>
            <property name="height_request">30</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_window_sidebar1_back_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">50</property>
            <property name="y">400</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

any ideas what could be causing this? And lets focus on the subject.

EDIT: heres my makefile

```
# change application name here (executable output name)
TARGET=ETE

# compiler
CC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
# debug
DEBUG=-g
# optimisation
OPT=-O0
# warnings
WARN=-Wall

PTHREAD=-pthread

CCFLAGS=$(DEBUG) $(OPT) $(WARN) $(PTHREAD) -pipe

GTKLIB=`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`  -rdynamic

# linker
LD=gcc
LDFLAGS=$(PTHREAD) $(GTKLIB) -export-dynamic

OBJS=   main.o

all: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: src/main.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) src/main.c $(GTKLIB) -o main.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Since the error message implicates your compilation options, don't you think your compilation and linking commands would be relevant?

Comment: Why is there a `void` before `gtk_close_window(secondWindow);`? Probably a mistake?

Comment: The callback prototype for GtkButton `clicked` signal is indeed wrong. Can you please add the code where you connect the signals and explain how is the code organized (single file or multiple files)?

Comment: Please don't add `[SOLVED]` to the title of a question. Instead, click the green checkmark next to the answer that solved it.

Comment: There is no "green checkmark" EDIT: you mean the grey checkmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY PROBLEM WAS AN ERROR ON THE USER END. I forgot to clean build on the end device and had some overlapping directories in there. When moving repositories, linux decided to prioritize the old ones. Problem is solved, and surprisingly, the code works.

EDIT:

i also switched to using

```
void on_sidebar1_back_clicked()
 {
    gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(secondWindow));
 }
```

instead of

```
void on_window_sidebar1_back_clicked() 
 {
    void
    gtk_close_window(secondWindow); //sedondWindow is defined further up. no errors related to it.
 }
```

and changed my signal to be a little shorter to avoid (human)memory problems.